# Difference between .NET Sockets from the AsyncState and the EndAccept() function

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, asyncsocket

When reading through this [Async Sockets example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te.aspx), I find this code:

```
    // Get the socket that handles the client request.
    Socket listener = (Socket) ar.AsyncState;
    Socket handler = listener.EndAccept(ar);
```

I'm having trouble finding documentation on what the difference between these 2 sockets is and I'd also like to know how shutting down the handler, or closing the handler will effect the original socket.  Can anyone explain this, or point me to some documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A socket is a unique connection on a particular machine i.e. `127.0.0.1:1024`.  Only one active connection can be made at a time.  The "listener" listens on a fix port (e.g. 1024 in my above example).  It's job is to be a "public" way of accepting connections.  Once it accepts a connection it creates a new socket on a new, randomly (well, reasonably pseudo-randomly), select port.  Then the original connecting application and the host can communicate over that socket freeing the listening socket to get another connection (which would dole out another port number for a new connection, and so on).

`EndAccept` is usually all you need to do once you've got a connection.  The `listener` usually goes on the listen for more connections to accept.  If not, you'll usually just dispose or close the socket to stop listening and cancel any pending accepts.  The `handler` is used to do whatever communication your application needs to, completely independently of the `listener` socket.  When you're done with the `handler` socket you dispose or close it and because the `listener` is independent it continues "running".

`Shutdown` will flush any pending data on a connection-oriented socket (to be called before `Close`) and won't affect any other sockets.

Answer (score 1):

The listener is the socket that is listening for connections. You don't want to keep the listener occupied otherwise multiple clients won't be able to connect via that socket. Calling EndAccept on that socket gives you a socket for the server to communicate with the client, and opens up the listener for more connections.

Closing the handler should not affect the listener socket.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  What about calling ShutDown() on the handler?  Any insight there?  Maybe I shouldn't need to call that at all -- which is fine, the Socket interface is a hodge-podge of methods that only make sense in certain usage-contexts.  So, my thinking is that I shouldn't need to ShutDown the handler.

Comment: You should probably shutdown the handler socket once you're done with it or that port is going to stay open until your process exits. Shutting down the handler socket won't affect the listener socket so you can still get incoming connections. Are you having a specific issue with your sockets?

Answer (score 1):

Any .NET server application based on sockets will involve at least two kinds of sockets:

1. A listener socket for listening for inbound connections (either synchronously or asynchronously)
2. A client socket which is returned by calling the Accept() method of the listener socket.

The example you are referring to is that of asynchronous listening, wherein the socket calls the BeginAccept() method first with the address of the async method as a parameter. Now if you don't call the corresponding EndAccept() method, the original listener socket will be blocked and any furthur connections coming from the client could be lost.

The Socket.ShutDown(Both) method is used to gracefully shutdown a socket with connections, whereas Socket.Disconnect(True) will do the same thing forcefully. In any case, Socket.Close() should follow these methods. See this SO link for more info on this: [c#/.Net Socket.Shutdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/583637/c-net-socket-shutdown)